# Polygon Marlin MEV don't work with python

Tags: web3.py, polygon, flashbots

I'm trying to send 3 transections with MEV Marlin using web3-flashbots. But if i'm trying to use example.py code from here(https://github.com/flashbots/web3-flashbots), i have a error with web3.flashbot.simulate().

```
    while True:
    block = w3.eth.block_number
    print(f"Simulating on block {block}")
    # simulate bundle on current block

    w3.flashbots.simulate(bundle, block)
```

Did someone can help me with it?

Error:

> ValueError: {'code': -32601, 'message': 'Method not found'}

Comment: Are you using the relay at http://bor.txrelay.marlin.org/ ?

Comment: @minhhn2910
yep. I'm find simulate method in web3-flashbots, but it handle to call_bundle() and don't have it in flashbots.py. So, i trying to find solution..

Comment: In their website they said that  "The relay only supports the eth_sendBundle RPC call at the moment. This means methods like eth_callBundle and related calls like simulate in the flashbots provider are not supported. Searchers will need their own instance or bor/mev-bor if they require the use of these methods." Did you consider this and run your own mev-bor node ? Link: https://docs.marlin.org/docs/User%20Guides/Polygon%20MEV/For%20Searchers

Comment: @minhhn2910
my bad, i miss it. But if i trying to send tx without simulating, a have error "ValueError: {'code': -32000, 'message': 'Please simulate on top of the latest block!'}"

UPD.
i mean w3.flashbots.send_bundle(